# Issues with Folium Grid Visualization

Tags: python, folium

I'm working on a grid visualization using Folium and Xarray in Python. The code is designed to display rectangles on a map, representing grid cells with associated wind speeds. The visualization works well when zoomed in, but becomes problematic when zooming out – at certain zoom levels, the rectangles are not visible.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import xarray as xr
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import folium

# Specify the URL of the NetCDF file
url = "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/sar/AKDEMO_products/APL_winds/tropical/2024/SH052024_BELAL/STAR_SAR_20240116013937_SH052024_05S_MERGED_FIX_3km.nc"

# Download the NetCDF file content
response = requests.get(url)
nc_content = BytesIO(response.content)

# Open the NetCDF file using xarray
dataset = xr.open_dataset(nc_content)

# Access the 'sar_wind' variable
sar_wind = dataset['sar_wind'].values

# Get latitude and longitude information from the NetCDF file
latitude = dataset['latitude'].values
longitude = dataset['longitude'].values

# Calculate the resolution of each grid cell
lat_resolution = abs(latitude[0, 1] - latitude[0, 0])
lon_resolution = abs(longitude[1, 0] - longitude[0, 0])

# Create a Folium map centered around the mean latitude and longitude
mean_lat = latitude.mean()
mean_lon = longitude.mean()
mymap = folium.Map(location=[mean_lat, mean_lon], zoom_start=10)

# Define color levels based on wind speed
speed_levels = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20,30]
speed_colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red',"purple"]

r = 2
# Iterate through each point and add a larger rectangle to the map
for lat, lon, wind_speed in zip(latitude.flatten(), longitude.flatten(), sar_wind.flatten()):
    # Calculate rectangle bounds based on lat, lon, and resolution
    bounds = [(lat - r * lat_resolution, lon - r * lon_resolution),
              (lat + r * lat_resolution, lon + r * lon_resolution)]

    # Determine color based on wind speed level
    color_index = next((i for i, level in enumerate(speed_levels) if wind_speed <= level), len(speed_levels) - 1)
    color = speed_colors[color_index]


    # Add rectangle to the map with no borders
    folium.Rectangle(
        bounds=bounds,
        color=color,
        fill=True,
        fill_color=color,
        fill_opacity=0.6,
        weight=0,  # Set weight to 0 for no borders
        popup=f'Wind Speed: {wind_speed:.2f} m/s'
    ).add_to(mymap)

# Save the map as an HTML file or display it in Jupyter Notebook
mymap
```

Explanation:

I'm using Xarray to handle NetCDF data and Folium to create a map with rectangles representing grid cells. The rectangles are colored based on wind speed levels. The resulting visualization, achieved through this method, is satisfactory. However, there are two noteworthy issues as outlined below.

[image]

Issue:

Upon zooming in on the map, it becomes evident that the rectangles lack perfect alignment. Although my preference is for them to be adjacent, there are instances of both overlaps and gaps.

[image]

When zooming out on the map, the rectangles shrink to the extent that they become too small to be visible. Beyond a certain zoom level, they eventually disappear altogether.

[image]

Questions:

- Is there a way to dynamically adjust the size of the rectangles based on the zoom level to ensure visibility?
- Are there any alternative approaches or parameters that could enhance the visibility of the rectangles when zooming out?

Here is an example in which the rectangles are all just next to other. You can zoom and click and you will see the rectangles. Here is the [link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000kufc/map?shakemap-code=us7000kufc&shakemap-source=us&shakemap-intensity=true&shakemap-mmi-contours=false&shakemap-stations=true)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I played around with adding Javascript to adjust rectangle size based on zoom, but was unable to make it work- though I do not believe its impossible.

Another approach could be layering, which allows you to toggle between views in the top right:

[image]

This will take some more fine-tuning than I have done to get the right rectangle sizes, but if you have multiple layers with different rectangle sizes and densities, you could just click whichever layer works best for the given zoom.

Again, I have not perfected the densities or sizes so the image is not perfect, but I believe it could work given some more trial and error. Notice it looks better when zoomed out:

[image]

But I cannot get the zoomed in portion to work right. If the rectangles were rotated (I could not find a Folium method of rotation besides a **lot** of work with the Polygon method) it could quite easily work. For now theres this, which could be better optimized:

[image]

but you could also just use your current code for the zoomed in layer. Again, if the coordinates created a perfect rectangle, there would be no overlap, and you could assign a density that would provide no gaps between rectangles. But while the coordinates create a parallelogram and not a rectangle, you will have those overlapping.

Anyways, heres my code for creating densities and changing rectangle sizes:

```
import xarray as xr
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import folium

url = "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/sar/AKDEMO_products/APL_winds/tropical/2024/SH052024_BELAL/STAR_SAR_20240116013937_SH052024_05S_MERGED_FIX_3km.nc"

response = requests.get(url)
nc_content = BytesIO(response.content)

dataset = xr.open_dataset(nc_content)

sar_wind = dataset['sar_wind'].values

latitude = dataset['latitude'].values
longitude = dataset['longitude'].values
print(latitude, longitude)

lat_resolution = abs(latitude[0, 1] - latitude[0, 0])
lon_resolution = abs(longitude[1, 0] - longitude[0, 0])

mean_lat = latitude.mean()
mean_lon = longitude.mean()
mymap = folium.Map(location=[mean_lat, mean_lon], zoom_start=10)

speed_levels = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30]
speed_colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', "purple"]


# define feature groups for varying densities
fg_low_density = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Low Density', show=True)
fg_high_density = folium.FeatureGroup(name='High Density', show=False)

# function to add rectangles with specified density and size adjustments
def add_density_rectangles(feature_group, density=1, is_high_density=False):
    step = max(1, int(len(latitude.flatten()) / (100 * density)))  # adjust to optimize
    size_factor = 5 if is_high_density else 30  # smaller size for higher density

    for i, (lat, lon, wind_speed) in enumerate(zip(latitude.flatten(), longitude.flatten(), sar_wind.flatten())):
        if i % step == 0:  # adjust frequency based on density
            # adjust rectangle size based on density
            adjusted_lat_resolution = lat_resolution * size_factor
            adjusted_lon_resolution = lon_resolution * size_factor
            bounds = [(lat - adjusted_lat_resolution, lon - adjusted_lon_resolution),
                      (lat + adjusted_lat_resolution, lon + adjusted_lon_resolution)]
            
            color_index = next((index for index, level in enumerate(speed_levels) if wind_speed <= level), len(speed_levels) - 1)
            color = speed_colors[color_index]
            
            folium.Rectangle(
                bounds=bounds,
                color=color,
                fill=True,
                fill_color=color,
                fill_opacity=0.6,
                weight=0  # No border
            ).add_to(feature_group)

# feature groups for different levels of detail
fg_low_density = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Low Density', show=True)  # Larger, fewer rectangles
fg_high_density = folium.FeatureGroup(name='High Density', show=False)  # Smaller, more rectangles

# add rectangles with specified densities and size adjustments
add_density_rectangles(fg_low_density, density=1.2, is_high_density=False)  # Lower density, larger size
add_density_rectangles(fg_high_density, density=35, is_high_density=True)  # Higher density, smaller size

# add both densities
mymap.add_child(fg_low_density)
mymap.add_child(fg_high_density)

# create layer control
mymap.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

mymap.save("layered_map.html")
```